# NSSavePanel, CGImageDestinationFinalize and OS X sandbox

Tags: core-graphics, osx-lion, sandbox, nssavepanel

I'm using NSSavePanel to let user select image to save to in my app. Everything worked fine until I enabled app sandboxing and entitlements. The problem occurs with selection of an already existing file. My code is like this:

// Create a URL to our file destination and a CGImageDestination to save to.
CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[savePanel URL], (CFStringRef)newUTType, 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgimage, (CFDictionaryRef)metaData);
const bool result = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination);

It works when selecting new file to save the image, but when I select existing file it creates strange named file besides existing file and fails to overwrite the contents of destination url. And even worse, I get no error in return and cannot detect the failure. Is this a bug in CoreGraphics or in my code? Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I get the same results for apple provided example MassiveImage http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MassiveImage/Introduction/Intro.html) if enable app sandboxing and entitlements. The only entitlement I use is com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write. Also I know that somehow overwriting existing file is possible in sandboxed app (standard app 'Preview' is sandboxed and overwrites existing images just fine).

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have discovered combination of core graphics calls to overwrite an already existing image working in sandboxed environment: `CGDataConsumerCreateWithURL` followed by `CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer`. So it seems `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` is broken (at least in `OS X Lion 10.7.1`) with sandbox enabled.