# Cannot Overwrite User Selected File from App Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac App that generates some data and write it to a file then asks the user where they want to save it and moves that saved file from the sandbox to the location they specify.  This works fine unless the user selects a file that already exists.  If the user presses "Replace" when OSX tells them that a file already exists, the NSError becomes non-nil with the following localized description.

> "testfile" couldn’t be copied to “Desktop” because an item with the
>   same name already exists.

How can I get this sandboxed app to overwrite the pre-existing file?

Thank you,
Stateful

Comment: Does the answer to this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884924/replace-a-file-using-the-nssavepanel-in-a-sandboxed-application

Comment: Yes it did!  Thank you very much, Merlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question provides the answer to my question:

[Replace a file using the NSSavePanel in a sandboxed application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884924/replace-a-file-using-the-nssavepanel-in-a-sandboxed-application)

Thank you, Merlin!